# Polynomial regression for parameter optimization

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation, python

I have a set of parameters that correspond to the processing of different diameter (OD) objects. I am looking to first find a way to accurately describe the relationship between Value 1 and Value 2 and then design an optimization algorithm to maximize the value of Value 1 and find the corresponding value of Value 2, you can see an example table below.

| OD | Value 1 | Value 1 / OD | Value 2 | Value 2 / OD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.7 | 24 | 1.89 | 60 | 4.72 |
| 19.05 | 23 | 1.21 | 86 | 4.51 |
| 25.4 | 18 | 0.71 | 77 | 3.03 |
| 15 | 22 | 1.47 | 47.5 | 3.17 |
| 22 | 22 | 1.00 | 79.8 | 3.63 |
| 28 | 20.1 | 0.72 | 81 | 2.89 |

I have been looking at using a polynomial regression model of the two values and calculating the maximum/minima to do this however I am not sure how robust this model is.

I do not have the best knowledge on statistics so I am hoping that you guys could tell me whether or not this is a valid approach or suggest a different area I should look at.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because your table uses different terms than your text, it is difficult (if not impossible) to relate the text to the table.  Please clear this up.  You really need to make your question more specific and focused, too: at present it looks like it might be trying to ask more than we are prepared to respond to in a single thread.  See our [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @whuber Sorry about that, I have edited to try and clear it up and make it more succinct. Please let me know if it is still not great and I will re-write the question.